# NodeJs not running in the port 4000

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I am trying to call an api using axios in react.I am using express and node js .when api is called using axios.get() .it returns error after some time.when i run node in port 4000(localhost:4000/data) its not loading.

```
  //api
  router.route('/issue').get((req, result) => {    
  Issue.find((err, issue) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        result.json(issue);
    });
  });

  //api call in react file
  axios.get('http://localhost:4000/issue').then(res=>{
        console.log('success');
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('error');
  });
```

Comment: What error message are you getting exactly?

Comment: You don't respond to the request in the error case...

Comment: It waits for  response .and returns this error ' GET http://localhost:4000/issue net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the error in your api.  If you just console.log, your frontend is still waiting for a response

And if your back don't sent any response, your browser cancel the request with a timeout, that is the error you got

```js
 //api
  router.route('/issue').get((req, result) => {    
  Issue.find((err, issue) => {
    if (err)
        result.status(404).json({
            success: false,
            msg: "There has been a problem in your request"
          });
    else
        result.json(issue);
    });
  });
```

Comment: thank you for response.I tried your suggestion .but it did nothing.Even if I run http://localhost:4000/issue in tab it doesn't work.

Comment: do you have more than 1 issue? Maybe you are doint a bad request 
 `Issue.find().then((err, issue) => {`

Comment: Glad it helped!
Keep hacking!